# Better way to structure a java class with many variables

Tags: java

I have a java class called Player. The mechanics on how the player file interacts with the server would take a lot to explain and I have no issues with the file, I just want to improve it and better my programming skills. So my question is, how would I take the many variables I have, ints, strings, booleans and make the code faster and more efficient/cleaner. Here is an example so you can see what the file looks like

```
enter code here
       public boolean usingGlory = false;
public int[] woodcut = new int [3];
public int wcTimer = 0;
public int[] mining = new int [3];
public int miningTimer = 0;
public boolean fishing = false;
public int fishtimer = 0;
public int fishXP;
public int fishies = 0;
public int fishreqt = 0;
public int fishitem = 0;
public int fishemote = 0;
public int fishies2 = 0;
public int fishreq2 = 0;
public boolean isfishing = false;
public boolean attemptingfish = false;
public int smeltType; //1 = bronze, 2 = iron, 3 = steel, 4 = gold, 5 = mith, 6 = addy, 7 = rune
public int smeltAmount;
public int smeltTimer = 0;
public boolean smeltInterface;
public boolean patchCleared;
public int[] farm = new int[2];
public boolean antiFirePot = false;
public boolean Lattack = false;
public boolean Lranged = false;
public boolean Lmagic = false;
public boolean Ldefense = false;
public boolean Lstrength = false;
public boolean Lspecial = false;
public boolean inPits = false;
public int pitsStatus = 0;      
public boolean inFunPk = false;
public boolean InDung = false;
```

Comment: Hmm, question might be better on [Code Review.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Tend to agree with @markspace. When you look at the names of your variables, it appears there may be redundancy. You may need to consider redesign and maybe adding more classes. Code Review might be a good place to post this and learn.

Comment: Yea so this source, the whole server is actually been built by others at some point in time and I am taking it and redoing a lot of their "bad code" and improving.

Answer (score 1):

You can break down the data into several classes, each of which contains information on a specific area.

For example, here, you have a group of variables that are related to fishing - these can be grouped into e.g. a `FishingComponent` class. There's also a group of information on smelting that could be split into a `SmeltingComponent` class, and so forth. This may lead to making the code more readable by taking groups of closely related information and functionality into their own classes.

For reusability's sake, you may wish to use an entity component system. These are popular in games programming as they allow the makeup of objects to be customised more than just inheritance. If there is, for example, an NPC that may hold information on fishing but does not have stats, the fishing component may be added to the NPC entity, and all of the code relating to fishing may be re-used.

You also mention making the code faster - unless you have a specific performance problem, you are probably attempting to prematurely optimise. However, you may wish to look into pooling objects if they need to be garbage collected a lot, as in games written in garbage collected languages, garbage collection cycles can be one of the biggest cause of framedrops.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to apply two common OOP techniques: **encapsulation and composition**. First of all, it's bad practice to have a bunch of `public` fields in your class. Instead, **encapsulate** them using **getter and setter methods**. Here's an example for the first two variables:

```
private boolean usingGlory = false;

public boolean isUsingGlory() {
    return usingGlory;
}

public void setUsingGlory(boolean using) {
    usingGlory = using;
}

private int[] woodcut = new int[3];

public int[] getWoodcut() {
    return woodcut;
}

public void setWoodcut(int[] woodcut) {
    this.woodcut = woodcut;
}
```

For more info, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

The second technique is **composition**. You're right not to like having so many variables in your class. Instead of having all the variables be part of the `Player` class, **group them into classes containing related items**. You can even group methods, when appropriate! Here's an example that uses your fishing variables:

```
public class Player {
    //...

    private FishingState fishingState = new FishingState();

    //Getter and setter

    //...
}

public class FishingState {

    private boolean fishing = false;
    private int timer = 0;
    private int XP;
    private int fishies = 0;
    private int reqt = 0;
    private int item = 0;
    private int emote = 0;
    private int fishies2 = 0;
    private int req2 = 0;

    //Getters and setters

    //A constructor and some methods:
    public FishingState(int XP) {
        this.XP = XP;
    }

    public void resetTimer() {
        timer = 0;
    }

}
```

Now, `player.fishemote = 3` becomes `player.getFishingState().setEmote(3)`. Longer, but clearer.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm definetly going to look into composition. The problem I know I am going to face is that the game has been built by others at some point in time so there is literately about 100 files that use this file so I have a lot of editing to do haha.

Comment: @Deviance in terms of encapsulation, many IDEs can do that encapsulation for you, and update other files accordingly.